# voting with javascript - form.onsubit

Tags: javascript, web, dom, frontend, backend

I'm making a website for my school (I'm 16 years old) and I need that when I submit a form, it can change things within the form itself.

I tried to do something using "this", but it didn't work. Can someone help me?

## HTML

```
<form class="form-votacao" name="form-votacao">
  <div class="participant-box">
    <img src="../images/blank.png" alt="blank" />
    <p id="name">participant name undefined</p>
    <p id="category">participant category undefined</p>
    <p id="talent-info">talent info undefined</p>
    <input
      type="submit"
      value="VOTAR"
      name="vote-button"
      id="vote-button"
    />
  </div>
</form>
```

## JAVASCRIPT

```
var form_votacao = document.forms["vote-form"];

form_votacao.onsubmit = function (event) {
  let fundo = this.querySelector(".participant-box")

  fundo.style.background = "green"
};
```

`As there will be several divs with the ".participant-box" class inside the form, I would like you to change only the div that I click on the submit button`

Answer (score 0):

First, I changed the button's type as `button`, because if you make its type as `submit`, then the form will be submitted, hence the javascript will be useless.

Below is the code using javascript to change the background of the parent div by clicking the button inside it.

Please click on the `Run code snippet` button for the demo.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.vote-button');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  });
});
```

```html
<form class="form-votacao" name="form-votacao">
  <div class="participant-box">    
    <p id="name">participant name undefined</p>
    <p id="category">participant category undefined</p>
    <p id="talent-info">talent info undefined</p>
    <input
      type="button"
      value="VOTAR"
      name="vote-button"
      id="vote-button"
      class="vote-button"
    />
  </div>
  
  <br/><br/>
  
  <div class="participant-box">    
    <p id="name">participant name undefined</p>
    <p id="category">participant category undefined</p>
    <p id="talent-info">talent info undefined</p>
    <input
      type="button"
      value="VOTAR"
      name="vote-button"
      id="vote-button"
      class="vote-button"
    />
  </div>
    
  <br/><br/>
  
  <div class="participant-box">    
    <p id="name">participant name undefined</p>
    <p id="category">participant category undefined</p>
    <p id="talent-info">talent info undefined</p>
    <input
      type="button"
      value="VOTAR"
      name="vote-button"
      id="vote-button"
      class="vote-button"
    />
  </div>
</form>
```

I hope I understood your situation.